# Java IDE Dialox Box Obscured (Intellij on Ubuntu)

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea Java IDE.  Much (but not all) of the time, the buttons on dialog boxes are cutoff.  I don't believe the problem is specific to Intellij, but it is the tool I use the most.  Most of the tools that do this are Java-based.  The panel at the bottom of the dialog appears to be the problem.

Does anyone know a solution for this?  I'd hate to hit the button confirming the destruction of something important.  Expanding the dialog box does not move the panel, it just resizes the entire dialog, leaving the buttons still obscured.

I am considering upgrading the JDK from 6 to 7, but not sure if that would solve it.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

[image]

Comment: Did you try switching themes(Look and feels) to see if you can reproduce the problem? It could be a problem with the 'Swing GTK look and feel' in your case.

Comment: @rimero: Do you know if IntelliJ Idea use Swing to create its own GUI?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, as far as I know, IntelliJ is written in Java Swing. It's easy to tell by looking at it vs SWT based applications for example.

Comment: Rimero, I'll switch them around and see.  Thanks for the Idea (pun intended).  The problem is that it is not consistent, so it is hard to say if it has an effect.  It seems to happen randomly.

Comment: Changing the theme from Alloy to GTK+ appears promising...The bottom white panel is gone using GTK+

Comment: It's a bug, most probably in Swing. Here's a ticket to vote/watch: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108541 . I haven't seen this so far on JDK 7 Update 40 (https://jdk7.java.net/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was similarly affected by this issue. Googling got me to this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1138517

and through that to this:

https://answers.launchpad.net/compiz/+question/229711

Following the steps on the second link to update my Compiz corrected the issue with the incorrectly rendered window bottoms. However I'm having another issue whenever I do the CTRL-Q thing in IDEA to bring up a Javadoc preview popup. The popup is missing the main menu bar and is unusually slow. Do you see the same issue?

Comment: I solved this by using JDK 1.7 instead of the standard 1.6.  Since then, I haven't had a problem.  I had a similar issue on Netbeans, too, and 1.7 solved the problem there as well.